# Changing the location (index) of a specific column in a dataframe within huge amount of columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, multiple-columns

I have a data frame consisting around 800 columns as follows,

```
 my_data:
    c1, c2, c3, ...,c340,...,c800
 0   1,  0,  1, ..., 0,...  ,  1
 1   1,  1,  0, ..., 1,...  ,  1
 ..  ..  ..
```

So, I want to move e.g., column "c340" to the end of the data frame like the position of c800 in the above example. Hence, me desired result should be like:

```
  my_data:
    c1, c2, c3, ...,...,c800,c340
 0   1,  0,  1, ...,...  ,  1, 0
 1   1,  1,  0, ...,...  ,  1, 1
```

I can use the below code to order the columns, but, since the numbers of columns are high, manually changing is not a good idea.

```
 my_data = my_data[['c1','c2',... 'c340']]
```

Comment: Show expected format and what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all i can think of for your particular problem

```
df_columns = my_data.columns.tolist()

df_columns.append(df_columns.pop(df_columns.index('c340')))  # ['c1','c2',...,'c800','c340']

my_data = my_data[df_columns]
```